# How to get instant average of some numbers when I add a new one

Tags: javascript, button, sum, average, calculator

I am new at programming and I've tried a lot to find something that could help me with that problem.

```
<form name="calc">
<input name="rezultat"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="2" onclick="run2()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="3" onclick="run3()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="4" onclick="run4()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="5" onclick="run5()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="6" onclick="run6()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="7" onclick="run7()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="8" onclick="run8()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="9" onclick="run9()"/>
<input type="button" name="1" value="10" onclick="run10()"/>
</form>
```

This is my HTML code

The idea is to make instant average of the numbers when I add a new one by clicking the specific button (every button has a value and an onclick proprety) and show that in the "rezultat" field.

I would be grateful if you'd help me with a script.

Comment: I said it already and I will repeat: "I am new at this domain"

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far. We might be able to point you in right direction.

Comment: <script>
function run2()
{document.calc.rezultat.value += ="2";}
function run3()
{document.calc.rezultat.value += ="3";}
function run4()
{document.calc.rezultat.value += ="4";}
function run5()
{document.calc.rezultat.value += ="5";}
</script>

Comment: And so on.. But the problem that in the field named "rezultat" is showing 2 when I click on "2" button and then, when I click on, for example, 3, it will show 23 . I want something that could calculate the average beetween 2 and 3 so "Rezultat" field will show "2,5" instead of 23. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Do you want it to be the average of *all* the buttons clicked, or only the last 2 buttons? IE if you click 2, then 3, then 5, will it take the average of (3+5)/2 or (2+3+5)/3?

Comment: Or do you mean the sum? Sum is adding the numbers together, average is adding all the numbers together, then dividing that by the number of numbers that were added.

Comment: I would like the average of all clicked buttons. Like your example, (2+3+5)/3.

Comment: Could anybody help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, most of the explanation is done inline in the comments.

```
<form id="calc" name="calc">
<input name="rezultat" id="rezultat" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="2" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="3" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="4" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="5" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="6" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="7" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="8" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="9" />
<input type="button" name="1" value="10" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0; // global scope variable
var total = 0; // global scope variable

// define your function to calculate a new value
var calc = function(e){

  // add value of button clicked to total
  total += Number(e.target.value);

  // add 1 to the counter
  count += 1;

  // set rezultat to average (total / count)
  document.getElementById('rezultat').value = total / count; 

  // stop bubbling and default handler
  return false;
}

// get array of the buttons in the form
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#calc input[type=button]');

// loop through the buttons
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){

  // bind a handler for the click event of each button
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click',calc,false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! You're a life-saver!

Comment: Then if you ever want to create a "reset" button, you could just add a simple function that just sets `count` and `total` to 0, then sets the value of `rezultat` back to 0 as well. :)